# jQuery API help

Tags: jquery

Do we have a document for jQUery 1.4.2..something that says this was there in 1.3.2 and has changed now in 1.4.2

Does the jQuery site has an official documentation that can be downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They DO have a change log, it's available at: http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.4.2/ and http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.4/ ... hopefully that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice if they had a change log, but this is the next best thing: [jQuery 1.4 Released – Full Release Notes](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14)

Answer (score 0):

In relation to the second part of your question, the documentation is obviously available online at [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com) but you can also download a Windows CHM file of it [here](http://charupload.wordpress.com/2007/12/07/jquery-documentation-chm/).